# Jquery conflict between two document ready functions

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a website which uses a couple of different pieces of jquery, now individually they both work fine on the page, but when you add them both one stops working.  Below are the two pieces of code that i believe are conflicting,

Is it because they both use

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
```

Below are the two pieces of code.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#example2').showbizpro({
                    dragAndScroll:"off",
                    visibleElementsArray:[5,4,3,1],
                    carousel:"on",
                    heightOffsetBottom:10,
                    mediaMaxHeight:[150,150,150,150],
                    rewindFromEnd:"off",
                    autoPlay:"off",
                    delay:2000,
                    speed:750
                });

                // THE FANCYBOX PLUGIN INITALISATION
                jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();

            });
```

And the second piece of code is

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
                skinsPath : 'skins/',
                skin : 'borderlessdark3d',
                thumbnailNavigation : 'hover'
            });
        });
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated as i anew to Jquery so any advice would be a help.  Thanks

Comment: jQuery event handling functions do not overwrite previous events so there should be no problem in having two `$(document).ready()` blocks. You can verify it by moving all code to a single block.

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When you debug this, does the code execute at all?  You can have all of the calls to `$(document).ready()` that you want, that shouldn't make a difference.  Can you provide a live example of the non-working code?

Comment: `Is it because they both use` no. It's more likely that you included jquery twice (which is a bad idea if you didn't already know that)

Comment: @KevinB -what? would you mind explain?

Comment: @imsiso there's nothing wrong with the code provided. If either work on their own but not together, then the only explanation for that is a conflict between the two. The most common cause of such a conflict is due to including a separate version of jquery for each one, resulting in the second inclusion of jquery overwriting the first.

Comment: THanks for the explanations and advice it;s all appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine the two blocks and use the "$" selector instead of "jquery"?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example2').showbizpro({
        dragAndScroll:"off",
        visibleElementsArray:[5,4,3,1],
        carousel:"on",
        heightOffsetBottom:10,
        mediaMaxHeight:[150,150,150,150],
        rewindFromEnd:"off",
        autoPlay:"off",
        delay:2000,
        speed:750
    });
    $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
        skinsPath : 'skins/',
        skin : 'borderlessdark3d',
        thumbnailNavigation : 'hover'
    });
    // THE FANCYBOX PLUGIN INITALISATION
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, combining the two worked perfectly, much appreciated.

Comment: If this fixed the issue it was by pure chance. I'm sure the OP inadvertently made some other changes on undisclosed parts of the code. 1) There's nothing wrong in having several `$(document).ready()` calls—even the official jQuery site [does it](http://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/js/main.js) 2) In fact, `jQuery` is more portable than `$` (which is often used by other frameworks)—but if you don't use other frameworks on the site they're just synonyms.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I've seen problems when using the jQuery token and not the $ token. I don't know, it doesn't make a lot of sense. Either way, two $().ready functions is just a no-no anyways. It's not good coding practice.